# How much time is required to slaughter the camel in order to recite quran after burial of ones parents?

Tags: sunnah

I recently came across the quote that says to read Quran after the burial of ones parents for the time in which a camel is slaughtered and distributed i wanna know how much time is enough or it takes to do that please help.

Comment: Please share the quote and its source. Have you ever considered checking its authenticity?